# python size of contents of dictionary value

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to find the size of values associated with a key in a dictionary.

```
dict = {0:({0,1,0},{0,2,1},{0,4,2}),1:{1,2,4},2:({2,3,2},{2,3,4}),3:{},4:{}}
```

For above, I want:

Key - Size

- 0 - 3
- 1 - 1
- 2 - 2
- 3 - 0
- 4 - 0

Comment: `for k in myDict: print(k, len(myDict[k]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a new dictionary with the actual keys and the length of the items corresponding to them, with *dictionary comprehension*, like this

```
>>> {num: len(d[num]) for num in d}
{0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 0, 4: 0}
```

Here, we iterate through the keys of the dictionary and then with `num: len(d[num])`, we use the same key as the new key and the length of the value corresponding to the key as the new value.

Comment: Or save the lookup each time: `{k:len(v) for k, v in d.items()}`

Comment: Well, you're grabbing the key, then doing a lookup to get values. so it's more efficient to just use `.items()` while building the `dict` instead of looking each key up to get the value

Comment: @JonClements Hmmm ya, it makes sense to use for the second case.

Comment: Also, don't forget that `{}` is an empty `dict` - not a `set`... so not quite sure what the `isinstance(value, set)` is supposed to be doing...

Comment: @JonClements I removed that part since I couldn't understand the req properly :(

Answer (score 0):

To match your desired output we have to specialcase `set`:

```
>>> print('\n'.join("{}-{}".format(key, 1 if isinstance(val, set) else len(val)) for key, val in dct.items()))
0-3
1-1
2-2
3-0
4-0
```